# Multiple validation in jqBootstrapValidation fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I am using `meteor` and `jade-handlebars` packages. Also using `coffeescript` for the javascript.
Now I am using `jqBootstrapValidation` to validate my form. I need to validate my phone number where the users can only input the integer of 10 digits only. So I did following in my jade file(it is only the part of my file)

```
.control-group
   label.control-label Phone Number
     .controls
       input(type='number',required='required',maxlength="10")
```

The validation for only the number is working but not the maximum length of 10 digit is not working also the number field is working for `chrome` not for `firefox`. Please help me out guys.
Thank You in advance.!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `maxlength` attribute only works for text inputs, not number inputs.

For ten digit phone numbers you need more validation than just a ten character number anyway, because valid numbers can contain `+-.` and lead with zeros. Instead use a text field with a regular expression defined in the `pattern` attribute. Here's an example that requires ten numerals:

```
<input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]{10}$" data-validation-pattern-message="10 digits needed">
```

In reality, your users probably want to be able to enter more complex phone numbers like `+44 (0)7772 123 456` or `1800-555-678`. There are some more powerful regexps listed in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation).